# In Documentation, code blocks in lists have to be indented less than in Q&A

Tags: bug, documentation, markdown-rendering

According to the [Markdown help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#advanced-lists), code blocks within lists have to be indented two levels, i.e., eight spaces, like this:

```
* Item

        Code
12345678
```

(Counter just for illustration). In Q&A, this renders as follows:

- Item

  ```
  Code
  ```

If I do the exact same thing in Documentation, I get this:

[image: Eight space indent in documentation]

Notice the extra white space in the code block (freehand red circle courtesy of Abhitalks). To get my code properly aligned, I have to use *six* spaces:

```
* Item

      Code
123456
```

resulting in

[image: Six space indent in documentation]

It should be the same everywhere, shouldn't it?

ETA: It wouldn't bother me (much), but because Ctrl+K toggles indentation and doesn't just add four spaces, there is no easy way to get two levels of indentation – so I often add a dummy character without indentation on the line before an indented code block and use Ctrl+K to indent again (and then delete the dummy character), but this breaks if the required indentation is six instead of eight spaces.

Comment: It’s a different Markdown engine AFAIK.

Comment: @JF: Why would they give it a different markup engine?

Comment: @NicolBolas I remember reading that they did, but I can't find the relevant post currently.

Comment: @NicolBolas I think they’re hoping to move Q&A to the new engine — [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org)

Comment: @BenjaminW.- There, added a freehand circle!

Comment: @Abhitalks Fantastic! _Now_ it makes sense ;)